# VBA - multiple sheet in a vba array

Tags: excel

Hi this macro  Private Sub Workbook_Open() insert in the various sheets the macro call_color but it does not work:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   'Dim ListaFogli As Variant
    Dim Foglio As Variant  
    ListaFogli = Array("MAX1", "MAX MAX", "MAX3", "MAX4", "MAX7", "MAX MAX MAX")    
    For Each Foglio In ListaFogli    
        Call color_cell        
    Next Foglio    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True  
End Sub


Sub color_cell()
  Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 3  
End Sub
```

a help?
Thanks you
max

Comment: All your sub does is colour A1 on the active sheet. You need to add a sheet argument.

Comment: Help to insert references to sheets?

Comment: @maxma62 you don't insert a reference (if by that you mean Tools > References?) You get a sheet by asking for it from the [`.Sheets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet) (or `.Worksheets`, there's a difference) collection of a workbook object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. There's no error trapping in case the sheet name doesn't exist but should start you off.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ListaFogli As Variant
Dim Foglio As Variant

ListaFogli = Array("MAX1", "MAX MAX", "MAX3", "MAX4", "MAX7", "MAX MAX MAX")

For Each Foglio In ListaFogli
    color_cell CStr(Foglio)
Next Foglio

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Sub color_cell(s As String)
    Worksheets(s).Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi SJR your macro for macro color_cell work well.
I changed the macro and added the macro imposta_pagina but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Hi SJR your macro for macro color_cell work well.
I changed the macro and added the macro imposta_pagina but it doesn't work

Private Sub Workbook_Open() 'SJR

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ListaFogli As Variant
Dim Foglio As Variant

ListaFogli = Array("MAX1", "MAX MAX", "MAX3", "MAX4", "MAX7", "MAX MAX MAX")

For Each Foglio In ListaFogli

```
                       'color_cell CStr(Foglio)
imposta_pagina CStr(Foglio)
```

Next Foglio

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub imposta_pagina(s As String) 'SJR

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$5"
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .CenterHorizontally = True
    .CenterVertically = True
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 30
    End With
```

End Sub

Comment: First, this is more of an edit to your question rather than an answer. Second you pass in `s` to `imposta_pagina` but you don't use it. Instead you use `ActiveSheet` `ActiveSheet` needs to be the sheet to which you'd like to apply your formatting. You can either pass in a sheet object or get a sheet object from `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(s)` or `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(s)`

Answer (score 0):

It's right?

```
Sub imposta_pagina(s As String) 'esempio 2 SJR

With Worksheets(s).PageSetup
   .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$5"
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
Worksheets(s).PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
With Worksheets(s).PageSetup
    .CenterHorizontally = True
    .CenterVertically = True
   .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 30
    End With
```

End Sub